# Installing WebSphere on red hat server 6.3 by command line?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Is there a way to install WebSphere application server 8.5 on RedHat Linux server  without GUI i.e. by command line?

I am using putty to access RedHat server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to install WAS using WebSphere Installation Manager.
See [WebSphere Installation Manager](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24035764)

Other option is an installation via console using configuration file.

[Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/tins_linuxsetup.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following link provides instructions for installing WebSphere 8.5 via command line using Installation Manager:

[Installing the product on distributed operating systems using the command line](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.installation.nd.doc/ae/tins_installation_dist_cl.html)